# reading the inbox of iphone email

Tags: iphone, cocoa, email, frameworks

I want to transfer data from my desktop pc/mac to my iphone app. To do so I think, that email is a good way.  Workflow: 
MAC sends email with data, iphone received email, application read the email (and the attached data) and works with it.

So now I search for a way to access (read only) the email inbox of the iphone via cocoa. Is there any framework to to so?

Comment: Why not use any of the 1000s of apps that do ~this? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, in general it's not possible for one application to access the data of another in iOS.

A few options:

- Put a web server on either the desktop or iPhone and download/upload the data
- Use a public web-service to (temporarily) host the data
- Encode the data as a URL and send that by email. Then the user would press the link which would start your app and import the data
- Allow the user to copy data over to the Documents directory of your application (iTunes file sharing). This is how Apple does it in Pages, Keynote, etc.
- DropBox (which has an API available)

Comment: I think DopBox is a good alternative. But iTunes file sharing sounds even interested. I will look on both.

Comment: I've tried DropBox - and it works fine (even it is a 0.xx SDK).

Answer (score 0):

As I know there's no such a framework in iOS SDK 4.2. You can only **send** emails within the app (In-App-Mail).